# Ansible - 'block' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve the Error message: ERROR! 'block' is not a valid attribute for a Play

How do I achieve this? I'm trying to use the "block" condition, but it's not working. I'm not sure what to search anymore.

Code:

```
---

- name: Get diagnostic info block
  block:
    - name: Get top process diagnostic info
      script: library/diag_top_processes.ps1
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: false
      register: diag_top_proc_out

    - name: Get memory and pagefile usage diagnostic info
      script: library/diag_memory_and_pagefile.ps1
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: false
      register: diag_mem_page_out

    - name: Get CPU info
      script: library/diag_cpu_info.ps1
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: false
      register: diag_cpu_info_out

    - name: Init diag message
      set_fact:
        diag_msg: "Diagnostic information:"
        proc_info:
          "{{ diag_top_proc_out.stdout|regex_replace('\r\n|\n|\r', '') }}"
        cpu_info: "{{ diag_cpu_info_out.stdout_lines | join(' ') }}"

    - name: Add top process info
      set_fact:
        diag_msg: "{{ [diag_msg, proc_info] | join(' ') }}"

    - name: Add memory info
      set_fact:
        diag_msg:
          "{{ [diag_msg, diag_mem_page_out.stdout_lines[0]] | join(' ') }}"

    - name: Add CPU info
      set_fact:
        diag_msg:
          "{{ [diag_msg, cpu_info] | join(' ') }}"

  rescue:
    - name: Diag info collection failed, setup variable
      set_fact:
        diag_failed: true
```

Error using 'block' for a Play:

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! 'block' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/home/keith/Ansible/ansible-role-high-cpu-usage-win/tasks/get_diagnostic.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Get diagnostic info block
  ^ here
```

Comment: You are using `block` in a play not in a task. I guess you are executing `ansible-playbook [your_file].yml`. You can see an example of how write a playbook here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution

Answer (score 3):

This file only correct if you do

```
- include_tasks path/to/get_diagnostic.yml
```

As lopez said, it cannot be called with ansible-playbook command line.

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite play as:

```
---
 - name: Play
   tasks:
    - name: Get diagnostic info block
      block:
        - name: Get top process diagnostic info
           script: library/diag_top_processes.ps1
           failed_when: false
           changed_when: false
           register: diag_top_proc_out
           ....
      rescue:
         - name: Another tasks
           ....
```